# jQuery Mobile + knockout.js performance problems and problems with a function

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

First of all, my english skills fell apart during the last years so I hope I can explain my problems exactly.

Im trying to write a garbage calendar app with an alarm, notification and so on if it might be ready some time.
At first you have to choose the right address of your city and due to that I know in which district the user is living and with that information I know when his garbage is being collected.
Right now I have two problems and I really can't fix them.

The first one is when I chose my address I'm coming to the address site where the address is shown and I have two buttons. The first one is: "Wrong address?" and the second one is "show me the dates for this district".
When I'm clicking the second option with the dates I'm calling my function doSomething3(sorry for those names) but if I'm coming to the page where the dates should be shown there is nothing shown on this page.

I figured out when im setting the variable viewModel.bezirksnr in the javascript file and for example navigate from the homescreen to the dates of districts with opening the same function its actualy workin so i guess my function isn't completly wrong.
The second observation I made is when I'm setting the variable, then pushing the button in the homescreen for showing me the dates (is working ofc) and then I'm setting an address and then push the button from my address site to show me the dates then something like this appears:

Every single date of the first attempt(with the variable set before starting the app) is followed by all of the dates of the new chosen district.

The second problem is the performance problems. When I selected an address and maybe I miss clicked and want to select another its not working. The app is so laggy and doesn't react anymore.

Due to this and cause of the pic I uploaded I guess maybe I'm not clearing the arrays in a right way but I tried for example the removeAll() for observable arrays but there was no effect.

Here is my index.html including all those pages:
http://pastebin.com/Zci009cn

And here is my javascript file:
http://pastebin.com/PwBdkBa0

I put them into pastebin for not creating a massive wall of text ;)

I hopefully could explain everything in an understanding way and it would be awesome if anyone can help me! if you have any questions, feel free to ask

Comment: Try creating a minimal test case and posting it here (though sometimes the very process of stripping it down will make it clear where the problem is). I suspect you just had too much code for people here to deal with.